# What is the return type of the following function in C++

Tags: c++

What does Typename mean? and what should the function return?

```
typename BSTMap<KEY,T>::TN* BSTMap<KEY,T>::find_key (TN* root, const KEY& key) const {..}
```

Comment: TN is most probably a typedef right ?

Comment: You may want to read the following http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html

Comment: It returns a pointer to `BSTMap<KEY,T>::TN`. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: BSTMap<KEY,T>::TN* obviously.

Answer (score 6):

The return type is `BSTMap<KEY,T>::TN*`.

The keyword `typename` is necessary to tell the compiler that nested name `TN` names a *type*. E.g. `TN` can be a nested typedef name, nested class type etc. This extra `typename` keyword is required almost always when you refer to nested names with `T1::T2` syntax, where `T1` part depends on template parameters.

Without it in many contexts the compiler would not be able to properly "understand" the code (like, for example, figure out whether `*` character declares a pointer, serves as unary dereference operator or serves as binary multiplication operator).